# Why use scala.collection.immutable.Stack

Tags: scala

I need something to store a LIFO. No need for traversing and other functions except for push and pop.

I've found special class in scala collection for creating a stack. But it lacks Nil object in pattern matching and other handy scala idioms. Immutable lists suit well at first glance, they have *cons* for construction and for extraction and that is all needed from LIFO.

Is there any reason behind scala.collection.immutable.Stack existence? Why I should prefer to use it, what are use cases to show its benefits?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From [the API documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stack.html):

> **Note:** This class exists only for historical reason and as an analogue
>   of mutable stacks. Instead of an immutable stack you can just use a
>   list.

And in [a little more detail](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html#immutable_stacks):

> Immutable stacks are used rarely in Scala programs because their
>   functionality is subsumed by lists: A `push` on an immutable stack is
>   the same as a `::` on a list and a `pop` on a stack is the same as a `tail` on
>   a list.

So to answer your questions:

1. Yes, there's a reason for its existence.
2. No, you shouldn't prefer it over lists.